# Ajuda com o KATA do Codewars partitionOn

Tags: javascript

O exercício que estou fazendo não deu erro nos testes, porém quando dou submit, ele dá erro, e eu não sei onde estou errando, alguém poderia me ajudar?

http://www.codewars.com/kata/525a037c82bf42b9f800029b/train/javascript

```
function partitionOn(pred, items) {
var sum_par = 0,
    sum_impar = 0;
var x = 0;    
for (var i in items) {
   if (pred(i) == true) {
       if (items[i] != undefined) {
          var par = items.splice(items[i]+1, 1);
          var impar = items.splice(par, 1);
          items.splice(1,0,par[0],impar[0]);
       }
   } else {
     sum_par += 1;
     items = sum_par;
   }
   x++;
}
return items;
}
```

Parâmetros de entrada:

1) parâmetro é um método de checagem (par ou ímpar) que retorna um valor booleano (true,false) e uma coleção numérica:

```
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
function isEven(n) {return n % 2 == 0}
var i = partitionOn(isEven, items);
```

2) a coleção também pode conter uma remoção com o método:

```
items.slice(0, i); //para retornar os ímpares
items.slice(i); //para retornar os pares
```